# Display SQL statement result into a label?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net

So here's what I have:

```
Dim connection As OleDbConnection = CompanyDB.GetConnection
Dim invoiceCount As String =
        "SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) " &
        "FROM Invoices " &
        "WHERE CustomerID = """ & customerID & """"
    Dim selectCount As New OleDbCommand(invoiceCount, connection)
    Try
        connection.Open()
        Dim reader2 As OleDbDataReader = selectCount.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleRow)


        If reader2.Read Then
            frmCustomerMaintenance.lblIncidents.Text = CInt(reader2("CustomerID")).ToString
        End If
        reader2.Close()
    Catch ex As OleDbException : Throw ex
    Finally : connection.Close()
    End Try
```

I keep getting an error on line 8:

```
Dim reader2 As ....
```

The error says

> Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

Am I missing something? Clearly it's a data type mismatch but I don't see how...

Answer (score 1):

Use parameters to fix your problem (and avoid SQL Injection):

```
Dim invoiceCount As String =
    "SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) " &
    "FROM Invoices " &
    "WHERE CustomerID = @customerID"

Dim selectCount As New OleDbCommand(invoiceCount, connection)
selectCount.Parameters.AddWithValue("@customerID", customerID)
```